# How to retrieve spring datasource properties from environment variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables

I'm building a spring boot application (spring boot 3.1.4, java 17). In my application.properties file I'm trying to retrieve properties value from environment variables.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/my_database
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER_DEV}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD_DEV}
```

At running, I got this error: `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${DB_USER_DEV}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

When I hard code username and password or set default value for environment variable it work fine:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/sponsorship_dev
spring.datasource.username=my_username # or ${DB_USER_DEV:my_username}
spring.datasource.password=my_password # or ${DB_PASSWORD_DEV:my_password}
```

From windows command line or powershell, `echo %DB_PASSWORD_DEV%` (cmd) or `$env:DB_PASSWORD_DEV` (powershell) return the good value.
I'm able to connect from MySQL CLI with the same credentials: `mysql -u my_username -p my_password my_database`.
I have excluded special characters: The characters <, >, |, &, and ^ are special command shell characters (this is from microsoft documentation).

PS: ${DB_HOST} and ${DB_PORT} are correctly retrieve.

Someone can help me please ?

Hard code credentials in properties is working.
Print environement variable is working.
Connection from mySQL CLI is working.

Comment: Just need to reboot my laptop... I don't think about it because I create DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME_DEV and DB_PASSWORD_DEV  environment variables at the same time and I was able to retrieve DB_HOST and DB_PORT. I just create a new environment variable DB_NAME_DEV and I have to reboot again to retrieve it from application.properties. Hope this post can help someone later...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using .env file for project environment variables during development, there is a separate plugin for intellij [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile)